# How does the basic XML editor in Eclipse evaluate xpath based on where the cursor is?

Tags: xml, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-wtp, pde, content-assist

I am trying to create a custom xml editor and mimic some functionality that the basic xml editor in eclipse provides. I can see that in the basic xml editor, it behind the scenes evaluates the xpath for where my cursor is in the xml files, and pulls the corresponding data from the xsd's and displays it. I can't seem to find resources to do this myself with my custom xml editor. I need to get the xml node based on where my cursor is. I have looked into DOM Parsers and SAX parsers but they don't solve the problem of retrieving the xml node that my cursor is on. I've looked into XPath Content Assistance also but can't seem to figure out how it works. I found this stack-overflow link, which still hasn't been answered well enough: [XPath aware XML templates or content assist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438420/xpath-aware-xml-templates-or-content-assist) 
This is definitely possible to do. What resources can I use?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/44785464/27905 .

The Eclipse Web Tools Platform XML Editor isn't doing anything with XPath for this. Most XML parsers are intended to convert from the source to a DOM or back, **without** preserving the underlying source, and if the source is in **any** way not well-formed, you're out of luck. To solve these and other problems, the WTP XML Editor relies on a custom fault-tolerant lexer and W3Cish DOM implementation on top of it. And then it builds out all of the other things you'd expect a proper source editor to provide, like Content Assist, the Outline view, Properties view, customizable syntax coloring, problem detection, etc.

When the XML contributions to the `org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.completionProposal` extension point are invoked, they look up the relevant DOM Node and text location and figure out what to propose. You can see how it's done against the DTD of XML Schema grammar using `org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui.internal.contentassist.AbstractXMLCompletionProposalComputer#computeCompletionProposals(CompletionProposalInvocationContext, IProgressMonitor)` or from the XML content assist templates that ship in the XML UI plug-in using `org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui.internal.contentassist.XMLTemplatesCompletionProposalComputer#computeCompletionProposals(CompletionProposalInvocationContext, IProgressMonitor)`.

If you're just trying to intelligently supply your own proposals, I'd encourage you to use the extension point that's provided.

Comment: the XPath-style path to the currently selected XML element is already displayed in Eclipse window's status bar. The basic xml editor in eclipse has this feature. How is the XPath-style path calculated here?

Comment: Again, it's not XPath, it's calculated by just walking up that custom DOM tree that's maintained in memory. You can see the algorithm at `org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui.StructuredTextViewerConfigurationXML#getStatusLineLabelProvider(ISourceViewer)` (http://git.eclipse.org/c/sourceediting/webtools.sourceediting.git/tree/bundles/org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui/src/org/eclipse/wst/xml/ui/StructuredTextViewerConfigurationXML.java#n205) Calculating a real, useful XPath would have required more resources.